# Error in installing shinyapps package from github

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, install.packages

I am trying to install the `shinyapps` package from its development page at Github to deploy my application to the `shinyapps.io` service. I am using the this code as described in http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/shinyapps.html

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/shinyapps')
```

However, I am getting the following error message:

```
Downloading github repo rstudio/shinyapps@master
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
Failed to connect to api.github.com port 443: Connection refused
```

Any idea about why and how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I made a more intensive search on this issue and I found that I needed to run this line:

```
install_github("hadley/pryr")
```

and then the line for installing shinayapps:

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/shinyapps')
```

It worked fine for me!

Comment: I think you meant,  `devtools::install_github("hadley/pryr")`?